# can we create multiple instance in a single AWS cloudFormation Template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-opsworks

I'm new to this AWS. I want n instances to be launched by running single Cloud Formation template.

WorkAround:

We went through the Auto-scaling group. But it appears condition to be mentioned to scale up. Besides we aren't clear with that concept.

Please guide us :

- Can we achieve this through Auto-scaling group..?
- Or is there any way to mention the count of no of instances to be launched in the CF template itself..?

Answer (score 2):

[Autoscaling can be done using the number of servers alone](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-as-group.html). It doesn't need to be triggered by alarms related to CPU or traffic. You simply describe "MinSize", "DesiredCapacity", and "MaxSize" to be the count of instances you want. If you want a specific number of instances, those numbers can all be the same.

The other way to do it is to specify several [AWS::EC2::Instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html)s in your template. If the machines are hetrogenous it may make more sense to do this.